# Как получить все значения по ключу из массива

Tags: python

Есть массив, состоящий из вложенных массивов:

```
a = [ 'id': 20, 'child': ['id':21,'id':22], "child": [ ["id":23,"id:34]]
```

Как мне получить список всех id в одну переменную?

Comment: А у вас код нерабочий, как минимум скобки не парные. Даже если поставить парную скобку, Python 2.7 не считает код валидным.

Comment: Это  для примера.

Comment: Любой код такого вида в Питоне будет нерабочим.

Comment: Для начала, определитесь - у вас всё-таки список или словарь. Если список - то никаких пар "ключ: значение" там быть не может. А если словарь - скобки должны быть фигурные, а не квадратные. И в словаре не может быть одинаковых ключей, то есть два "id" внутри одного словаря не будут корректно работать.

Comment: @Александр в некоторых языках (не в Питоне) используют термин ассоциативный массив, который может по ключу доступ предоставлять (в PHP как индексируемый массив (аналог списка в Питоне) так и массивы с именованными ключами (аналог словаря) можно создать, используя одну функциею [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Это вероятно является источником терминологии в вопросе.

Comment: @jfs Возможно, но и в названии вопроса, и в тексте упомянут только Python

Answer (score 4):

Если под *"массивом"* в вопросе подразумевается [ассоциативный массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) ([Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping), словарь в Питоне),  который может содержать вложенные [индексные массивы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29) ([Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), список в Питоне), которые в свою очередь могут содержать ассоциативные массивы, итд, то достаточно легко написать рекурсивную функцию, которая вернёт все значения, соответствующие заданному ключу:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Sequence, Mapping

def get_all_values(seq_or_mapping, key):
    """Get all values from *seq_or_mapping* with the *key* recursively."""
    items = getattr(seq_or_mapping, 'items', lambda: enumerate(seq_or_mapping))
    for k, value in items():
        if k == key:
            yield value
        if isinstance(value, (Sequence, Mapping)):
            yield from get_all_values(value, key) # yield nested values
```

Пример:

```
nested = {'id': 20,
          'child': [{'id': 21}, {'id': 22,
                                 'child': [{'id': 23}, {'id': 34}]}]}
print(*get_all_values(nested, 'id'))
# -> 20 21 22 23 34
```

В примере представлена только одна из нескольких возможных интерпретаций структуры, показанной в вопросе (она неоднозначна), но на итоговый набор `id` это никак не влияет.

Если ключ целый, то функция также возвращает значения с соответствующим индексом из каждого списка (или словаря по ключу `0`), например:

```
print(*get_all_values(nested, 0))
# -> {'id': 21} {'id': 23}
```

Строка (`str`) также является `Sequence` (последовательностью) в Питоне, поэтому если хочется рассматривать строку как скалярную величину, то следует явно исключить этот тип (добавить в тело цикла в примере кода выше до рекурсивного вызова):

```
if isinstance(value, str):
    continue # переходим к следующей паре ключ, значение
```

Вместо `getattr()`, можно было бы использовать обобщённую функцию, чтобы различить список и словарь, такую как [`get_items()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101711/4279).

Если структура может быть очень глубоко вложена, то [вместо рекурсии можно использовать явный стек с циклом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081150/4279):

```
def get_all_values(seq_or_mapping, key):
    stack = [seq_or_mapping]
    while stack:
        seq_or_mapping = stack.pop()
        for k, v in get_items(seq_or_mapping):
            if k == key:
                yield v
            if isinstance(v, (Sequence, Mapping)):
                stack.append(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

def getAllKey(obj: iter, key='id'):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k == key: yield v
            elif isinstance(v, collections.Iterable): yield from getAllKey(v)
    elif isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
        for ob in obj: yield from getAllKey(ob)

a = ({'id':20,"child":[{"id":23},{"id":34},{'child':[{'id':21},{'id': 22}]}]},{'id': 11})
r = list(getAllKey(a))
print(r)
```

out:

```
[23, 34, 21, 22, 20, 11]
```

Comment: 1- `getAllKey()` не очень удачное имя (функция возвращает все значения, а не ключи. Можно было бы назвать: [`get_all_values()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/567105/23044) 2- Если нет особых причин для обратного, старайтесь придерживаться pep-8 соглашений о именах, а именно вместо `camelCase`, использовать: `lower_case_with_underscores` для имён функций. 3- значение по умолчанию для `key` возможно не стоит здесь использовать—функция никак под специально `'id'` не специализирована.  Если вы используете `collections.Iterable`, то можно и `collections.Mapping` вместо dict использовать тогда.

Answer (score 1):

В комментарии к вопросу я уже написал, почему описанную вами структуру нельзя запихнуть ни в список, ни в словарь.

Нужно искать альтернативную структуру данных.
Как вариант, можно использовать список кортежей: в списке будут содержаться 2х-элементные кортежи, в котором нулевой элемент - то, что у вас было ключом (id или child), а первый элемент - то, что у вас было значением (число для ключа id или список для ключа child).

Таким образом ваша структура будет выглядеть так:

```
a = [('id', 20), ('child', [('id', 21), ('id', 22)]), ("child", [("id", 23), ("id", 34)])]
```

А код для получения списка всех id будет таким:

```
ids = []


def proceed(lst):
    for tpl in lst:
        key, value = tpl
        if key == 'id':
            ids.append(value)
        if key == 'child':
            proceed(value)

proceed(a)
print(ids)

# Код выведет: [20, 21, 22, 23, 34]
```

Это самый простой/примитивный вариант. Я бы на такой задаче, возможно, ввёл бы отдельные два класса для id и child и всю логику инкапсулировал бы в них. Ну или вообще избавился бы от ключей и хранил эту информацию так:

```
[20, [21, 22], [23, 34]]
```

Но это сильно зависит от конечной задачи.