# Как получить индекс элемента словаря (ассоциативного массива) в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

Есть словарь с данными:

```
active_object.data.groups['foo']
active_object.data.groups['bar']
...
active_object.data.groups['ets']
```

Я перебираю все его элементы в цикле:

```
for object in active_object.data.groups:
```

И мне нужно получить ключ `'foo','bar'...'ets'` (не порядковый номер), чтобы найти соответствующий элемент в другом словаре (ассоциативном массиве). Какой способ наиболее приемлемый для этого? По сути мне нужен аналог PHP `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`

Comment: В отличии от php в питоне принято различать *списки* (индексный массив)  и *словари* (ассоциативный массив). Ваш код уже перебирает все возможные ключи в словаре: `for key in some_dict` Связанный вопрос: [Как получить все значения по ключу из массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566649/23044) Упомяните в заголовке вопроса для ясности, что вы хотите: индексы (целые числа) из списка или ключи (любой hashable объект) из словаря.

Comment: я, в принципе нашел решение `for key, object in active_object.data.groups.items():` вот что мне нужно было

Comment: цикл с items() соответствует приведённому php циклу, но НЕ соответствует словесному описанию проблемы в вопросе. items() возвращает все пары ключ,значение из словаря. Поправьте вопрос, если вы именно это хотели, чтобы его могли найти люди с похожим вопросом и наоборот, чтобы меньше  людей ошибочно его находили (чтобы полезный был) Если думаете что нашли решение, то [опубликуйте его как свой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs исправил, так подойдет?

Comment: как я уже сказал выше "индекс элемента" в Питоне это целое число, а не пара ключ/значение. Для людей с похожим заблуждением, явно упомяните это в вашем ответе. Словарь не имеет порядка в Питоне—не имеет смысл даже спрашивать на каком месте (индексе) заданная пара ключ/значение находится.

Comment: Вопрос противоречит себе: php код возвращает как ключ так и значение на каждой итерации, но слова в вопросе говорят что вам нужны только ключи, которые вы в *другой* словарь передавать собрались (значения из текущего словаря не нужны).

Comment: @jfs ну и что, не вижу ничего криминального в этом. Обычно нужны и ключи и значения

Comment: Что "обычно" происходит не важно, мы говорим о вашем конкретном вопросе. Отредактируйте *текст* вопроса  и укажите, что вы хотите как ключ так и значение. Потому что если вам нужен только ключ, тогда `items()` это неправильный ответ: данный метод не возвращает ключи, он возвращает пары ключ/значение. А правильный ответ был бы: `for key in active_object.data.groups:` (обратите внимание, что если `groups` это словарь, то возвращаются именно ключи, а не значения). Не страшно, если вопрос имеет неверную терминологию, если ответы точно говорят какая терминология правильная.

Comment: Так ведь возвращается именно объект, а не ключ, значит это не словарь, а ассоциативный массив?

Comment: "Словарь" это имя для "асоциативного массива" в Питоне. Запустите `python` команду, чтобы REPL появилась (можно online) и поиграйтесь со словарём: `d = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)` Посмотрите, что возвращают: `list(d)`, list(d.keys()), `list(d.values())`, `list(d.items())`. Определитесь, что вы хотите получить в вашем случае и обновите вопрос соответственно. Посмотрите в словаре значения слов: dictionary, keys, values, items. Как ключи так и значения в словаре являются объектами в Питоне.

Comment: @jfs я не знаю что там на самом деле, эти данные уже забиты в Blender и я понятия не имею в каком они виде. Но list(d) возвращет значения, а не ключи: http://itmag.es/1Ovcy

Comment: Что type(d) показывает?

Comment: `>>> type(bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.groups)

<class 'bpy_prop_collection'>`

Comment: поиск по имени класса, говорит что это какая-то специализированная коллекция, а не список или словарь. И если  `list(d)` равен `list(d.values())`, а не равен `list(d.keys())`, то он не ведёт себя как словарь (для которого всегда: `list(d)==list(d.keys())`). В этом случае,  лучше явно тип groups указать со ссылкой на документацию (знание поведения списков, словарей в Питоне не поможет в этом случае). Кстати, если когда либо будете создавать свои классы для коллекций, то старайтесь следовать Sequence или Mapping протоколу, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить пары ключ,значение из словаря с помощью `items()`:

```
for key, object in active_object.data.groups.items():
```