# Python Списки \ массивы

Tags: php, python

Здравствуйте!
В PHP массив можно записать таким образом:

```
$array[$index]['example'] = "My text";
```

Как провернуть подобную операцию в Python?

Comment: `array[index]['example'] = "My text"`

Comment: Поясните вопрос, чего конкретно Вы хотите добиться? Вам необходимо хранить значение по ключам или по индексам, какие-нить комбинированные варианты? Посмотрите книгу Python к вершинам мастерства, буквально на первых страницах куча вариантов реализации.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это векторный массив содержащий словари(кучи). Вам стоило бы это указать.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python: Как получить все значения по ключу из массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566649/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то в Python подобное невозможно. Вы сначала должны создать контейнер, а уже потом добавлять в него элементы. В PHP происходит ровно тоже самое, но интерпретатор, скрывает это от Вас. Для вашего примера, контейнер скорее всего будет списком или словарём. Контейнера будет — два. В качестве элемента первого контейнера — второй контейнер. Его тоже нужно сначала создать, а потом добавлять в него элементы.

Существует несколько вариантов, сделать то что вы хотите. Конкретный вариант, зависит от решаемой задачи.

Самое простое — представить вашу структуру данных в виде вложенных словарей.

**Вариант 1.**

```
some = dict() 
some[index] = dict()
some['example'] = 'My text'
```

**Вариант 2.**
Тоже самое можно написать более лаконично:

```
some = dict() 
some[index] = dict(example='My text')
```

**Вариант 3.**
Насколько я понимаю `index` — это число.
В таком случае, его не удастся подсунуть как аргумент в конструктор `dict()`.
Но при этом можно воспользоваться литерной формой словарей.

```
some = {
    index: {
        'example': 'My text'
    }
}
```

**Вариант 4.**
Это все хорошо, но что делать, если нужен все-таки список, а не словарь.

```
some = list() 
some += [dict(example='My text')]
```

Тут мы создали список, и положили в качестве его первого элемента словарь.
«К сожалению», списки нумеруются с «0», и далее по порядку.
Т.е. нельзя заполнить элементы «5», «10», «25», а остальные не заполнять, как в PHP или Perl.

Если в списке всего один элемент, то можно сократить:

```
some = [dict(example='My text')]
```

**Вариант 5.**
Я бы предложил посмотреть в сторону [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). Возможно, исходная задача лучше ляжет на методы из этого модуля.

**Вариант 6.**
Если вы реализуете список данных сложной структуры, то правильнее это делать классами. Так будет проще контролировать происходящее.

Comment: Если не стоит *явного* требования в вопросе эмулировать каждый баг  в php, то `array[index]['example'] = "My text"` уже достаточным ответом может быть (хотя не известно, что автор хочет). Можно долго гадать, что нужно: `array = [{'example': 'My text'}]` или `array = vividict();`, где `vividict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(vividict)` или `array.append({'example': 'My text'})` или `array[index] = d` или что-то другое -- слово "невозможно" не стоит употреблять, тем более что  мы не знаем точной постановки задачи.

Comment: @jfs Я уверен, что понял, в чем был исходный вопрос. В компании N, пересаживали старых прожженных перловиков на Python. И я буквально каждый день слышал аналогичные вопросы. Очевидно, что товарищи хотят достичь привычной семантики, с максимально привычным синтаксисом, наиболее стандартными средствами языка с наименьшим количеством конструкций. Баг \ не баг — вопрос спорный.

Comment: у каждого языка свои идиомы. Не нужно поощрять написание X языка, используя Y синтаксис (если пишите на Y, то и используйте приёмы принятые на Y). Этой теме много лет. Как известно: [*"the determined Real Programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language."*](http://web.mit.edu/humor/Computers/real.programmers)

Comment: А как действовать? Говорить, «иди почитай, что-нибудь про питон». По моему опыту, это не работает. Внешнее структурно-семантическое сходство идиом работает как «ложные друзья переводчика». Иногда помогает, иногда — мешает. Если о таких друзей кто-то споткнулся, кажется, лучше рассказывать, о разнице, и по возможности ее объяснять. По крайней мере, к этому я стремился в своем ответе.

Comment: "как действовать?" Шаг №1 уточнить какую действительную задачу человек хочет решить  Шаг №2 предложить решения подходящие для выбранного языка. См. варианты из моего первого комментария.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что типы данных в разных языках используют одни и те же. Принципы работы с ними тоже примерно одинаковые.

Поэтому ответ будет: *точно так же как написали вы, только без знака доллар*.