# Как сделать поиск по словарю в python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, словари

Как сделать поиск по словарю в python3?
Есть словарь вида:

```
 emploers = {'id1':{'name':"Джон", 'Familia':"Трамп", 'Otchestvo':"Дональдович", 'Telefon':"33-33-33"},'id2':{'name':"Владимир", 'Familia':"Путин", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon':"8(912)911911911"}}
```

Мне нужно при вводе  значения name вывести скажем значение Telefon.
Делаю вот так:

```
for search_emploers in emploers:
    name1 = input("Введите имя ")
        if emploers[search_emploers]['name'] == name1:
            print(emploers[search_emploers]['Telefon'])
        else:
            print('нет такого значения')
```

Но мне выводит поиск только по первому словарю а потом еще раз задает тот же вопрос.
Подскажите как реализовать данный функционал, я начинающий в Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
employer = {'id1': {'name': "Джон", 'Familia': "Трамп", 'Otchestvo': "Дональдович", 'Telefon': "33-33-33"},
            'id2': {'name': "Владимир", 'Familia': "Путин", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon': "8(912)911911911"}}

name1 = input("Введите имя: ")
flag = True

for search_emploers in employer:
    if employer[search_emploers]['name'] == name1:
        print(employer[search_emploers]['Telefon'])
        flag = False

if flag:
    print('нет такого значения')
```

Тут просто ввод данных нужно было вынести из цикла.

Лично я бы реализовал это так:

```
flag = True
name_id1 = input("Введите имя: ")
for i in employer:
    if employer.get(i).get('name').upper() == name_id1.upper():
        print(employer.get(i).get('Telefon'))
        flag = False
if flag:
    print('Имя не найдено')
```

Метод `upper`(переводит строку в верхний регистр) добавил для того, чтобы избежать несовпадений в регистре.

Вывод нескольких значений:

```
if employer[search_emploers]['name'].upper() == name1.upper():
    print(employer[search_emploers]['name'], employer[search_emploers]['Familia'])
```

Comment: а почему если я это все добавляю в функцию не работает.

Comment: @Artem В какую именно функцию?

Comment: for search_emploers in emploers:

Comment: Вот спасибо! помогли очень! еще и разные варианты.

Comment: @Artem скопируйте полностью код вставьте в новый файл, тогда точно заработает. Заметьте, в коде я поправил граматическую ошибку в слове employers. Правда у меня переменная записана в единственном числе, но это не имеет значения

Comment: print(employer[search_emploers]['name']['Familia']['Telefon'])
Добавил несколько ключей при выводе теперь ошибку выдает:
Введите имя: Владимир
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dicttest1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(employer[search_emploers]['name']['Familia']['Telefon'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Artem Когда вы вводите `employer['name']` вы получаете значение под этим ключом, т.е. Джон или Владимир, если вы хотите вывести несколько значений, то делайте это постепенно. Пример добавил в ответе

Answer (score 3):

```
In [8]: def _get(dct, name, value):
   ...:     result = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('name') == name, dct.values()))
   ...:     return result[0][value] if result else False
   ...:

In [9]: _get(emploers, 'Джон', 'Telefon')
Out[9]: '33-33-33'

In [10]: _get(emploers, 'Karl', 'Telefon')
Out[10]: False
```

Comment: `next(d['phone'] for d in dct.values() if d['name'] == name)`

Answer (score 2):

```
emploers = {'id1': {'name': "Джон", 'Familia': "Трамп", 'Otchestvo': "Дональдович", 'Telefon': "33-33-33"},
            'id2': {'name': "Владимир", 'Familia': "Путин", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon': "8(912)911911911"},
            'id3': {'name': "Владимир", 'Familia': "Иванов", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon': None}}

def get(emploers=emploers, **keys):
    ki = keys.items()
    for i in emploers:
        dt = emploers[i]
        if all((dt[k] == v) for (k, v) in ki):
            yield dt

g = get(Otchestvo="Дональдович")
print(next(g)['Telefon'])  # 33-33-33

g = get(name="Владимир", Otchestvo="Владимирович")
print(next(g)['Familia'])  # Путин
print(next(g)['Familia'])  # Иванов
```

Comment: чересчур усложнёно. Можно [проще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790026/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы реализовать [`jq` команду](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), которая печатает телефон по заданному имени из `input.json` файла:

```
$ jq -r '.. |  select(.name? == "Владимир") | .phone' input.json
```

на Питоне достаточно `input()` поднять из цикла наверх в вашем коде:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

name = input('Введите имя')
for person in presidents.values():
    if person['name'] == name:
        print(person['phone'])
```

где `input.json` файл, переданный в командной строке, загружен в `presidents` словарь:

```
import fileinput
import json

data = "".join(fileinput.input(openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")))
presidents = json.loads(data)
```

Чтобы найти объекты с указанным именем на любом уровне вложенности (как это приведённая выше `jq` команда делает), можно рекурсивное решение использовать:

```
def get_all_dicts(seq_or_mapping, predicate):
    if hasattr(seq_or_mapping, 'values'):  # mapping
        if predicate(seq_or_mapping):
           yield seq_or_mapping  # found
        values = seq_or_mapping.values()
    else:  # sequence
        values = seq_or_mapping

    # check nested collections
    for value in values:
        if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
            yield from get_all_dicts(value, predicate)  # recursion
```

См. [Как получить все значения по ключу из массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566649/23044). Пример:

```
nested = {'results': [{'name': 'Trinity', 'phone': '312-555-0690'}]}
for d in get_all_dicts(nested, lambda d: d.get('name') == 'Trinity'):
    print(d['phone'])  # -> 312-555-0690
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import json

def get_all_dicts(seq_or_mapping, predicate):
    if hasattr(seq_or_mapping, 'values'):  # mapping
        if predicate(seq_or_mapping):
            yield seq_or_mapping  # found
        values = seq_or_mapping.values()
    else:  # sequence
        values = seq_or_mapping

    # check nested collections
    for value in values:
        if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
            yield from get_all_dicts(value, predicate)  # recursion

# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    nested = json.loads(document['content'].value)
    for d in get_all_dicts(nested, lambda d: d.get('name') == document['name'].value):
        document <= html.P(d['phone'])
</script>
<div><label for="content">JSON: <textarea id="content" rows=10 cols=30>{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Trinity",
      "phone": "312-555-0690"
    }
  ]
}</textarea></div>
<div><label for="name">Имя: <input id="name" value="Trinity"></div>
<div><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></div>    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Перебор и сравнение:

```
def my_find(employer, name):
    for k, v in employer.items():
        if v['name'] == name:
            print(v['Telefon'])
            return

    print('Не найдено: "{}"'.format(name))


employer = {
    'id1': {
        'name': "Джон", 'Familia': "Трамп", 'Otchestvo': "Дональдович", 'Telefon': "33-33-33"
    },
    'id2': {
        'name': "Владимир", 'Familia': "Путин", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon': "8(912)911911911"
    }
}

name_id1 = input("Введите имя: ")

my_find(employer, name_id1)
```

Comment: ключи не используются у вас. Можно заменить .items() на .values(). Можно `v` на `person` заменить¶ Начинающие путаются с return против print. Функция либо то либо другое для результата должна использовать (лучше return: не смешивайте чистые вычисления и ввод/вывод): `def get_by_name(dicts, name, property): return next(d[property] for d in dicts if d['name'] == name)`

Comment: Ваш вариант ответа не работает если в словарь будет расширен и встретиться несколько например "Владимир"
employer = {'id1': {'name': "Джон", 'Familia': "Трамп", 'Otchestvo': "Дональдович", 'Telefon': "33-33-33"},
            'id2': {'name': "Владимир", 'Familia': "Петров", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon': "555-555-55"}, 
            'id3': {'name': "Владимир", 'Familia': "Иванов", 'Otchestvo': "Владимирович", 'Telefon': "999-999"}}