# Как получить данные из вложенного словаря Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть подобный словарь

```
{
    "address": "0x544444444444",
    "ETH": {
        "balance": 444,
        "totalIn": 444,
        "totalOut": 4
    },
    "countTxs": 2,
    "tokens": [
        {
            "tokenInfo": {
                "address": "0x44444",
                "name": "fdf",
                "decimals": 0,
                "symbol": "dsfdsf",
                "totalSupply": "3228562189",
                "owner": "0x44444",
                "lastUpdated": 1519022607901,
                "issuancesCount": 0,
                "holdersCount": 137528,
                "price": false
            },
            "balance": 5000,
            "totalIn": 0,
            "totalOut": 0
        },
        {
            "tokenInfo": {
                "address": "0x44444",
                "name": "ggg",
                "decimals": "2",
                "symbol": "fff",
                "totalSupply": "250000000000",
                "owner": "0x44444",
                "lastUpdated": 1520452201,
                "issuancesCount": 0,
                "holdersCount": 20707,
                "price": false
            },
            "balance": 500,
            "totalIn": 0,
            "totalOut": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Как получить значение ключа "name" из первого и второго словаря без использования json библиотеки.

Comment: я вижу ~6 json-объектов (у словарей в Питоне другой repr). В командной строчке, можно [`jq -r '.. | .name? | select(. != null)'`](https://jqplay.org/s/sKuPJOw9AR) запустить. Связанный вопрос: [Basic jq usage. How to get nested value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41712363/4279)

Comment: Допустим на входе `nested` словарь: какой ответ вы ожидаете? `[d['tokenInfo']['name'] for d in nested['tokens']]` или что-то другое? Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать поиск по словарю в python3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789971/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

словарь = obj;

```
    obj['tokens'][0]['tokenInfo']['name'] - 1 имя 
    obj['tokens'][0]['tokenInfo']['name'] - 2 имя
```